# Flutter/Dart speech to text plugin for Dart 2.1.0+

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a speech-to-text plugin that works for the more recent versions of Flutter/Dart?

When I try to use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/speech_recognition, I get the error below:

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-4cf2d3990b.
>
> Because speech depends on speech_recognition any which requires SDK >version <2.0.0, version solving failed.
>
> pub get failed (1)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that package is outdated : Jun 12, 2017  , you could fork the project and update the constraints or you can use any repo updated from another user.

I saw there are already issues opened and also PR sent.

You can use the repo updated from this user :

(In your pubspec.yaml)

```
speech_recognition:
    git: https://github.com/OsmanBrito/speech_recognition
```

Comment: Thanks @diegoveloper. Any thoughts on location of Swift lanaguage config parameter appreciated.
    === BUILD TARGET speech_recognition OF 
    PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) 
    build setting must be set to a supported value for 
    targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the 
    build settings editor.
    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone X.